# How to use "URLencode"?

Tags: php

I would like to encrypt my URL to prevent users from modifying it,
because I get the values in the URL to display them in a form.

For now I have this URL:

```
indexTest.php?client=Balmain&jira=Evo8&contact=Balmain@yahoo.fr
```

and the URL I want:

```
indexTest.php% 3Fclient% 3DBalmain% 26jira% 3DEvo8% 26contact% 3DBalmain% 40yahoo.fr
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" >
   <head>
       <title>Envoi de paramètres dans l'URL</title>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php
$userinput = "client=Dupont&jira=Jean&contacte=dupont@yahoo.fr";
echo '<a href="indexTest.php?', urlencode($userinput), '">';
?>
   <p><a href="indexTest.php?client=Balmain&jira=Evo8&contacte=Balmain@yahoo.fr">Cliquer ici pour remplir le formulaire!</a></p>
   
   <p><a href="indexTest.php?%3Fclient%&3A=Balmain&%26jira%&3B=Evo8&%26contacte%&3C=Balmain%40yahoo.fr">Cliquer ici pour remplir le formulaire!</a></p>
   
   </body>
</html>
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: _"I would like to encrypt my URL to prevent users from modifying it"_ - That has nothing to do with `urlencode()` which _encodes_ the string, not _encrypts_ it. Encoding is just to make non url friendly characters (or characters that has special meaning in a URL) and make them URL friendly.

Comment: Users are always going to be able to modify a URL. The key is to ensure there aren't any unpleasant side effects when they do.

Comment: If you don't want them to be able to change the parameters, you need to use some proper encryption (using some secret key) to encrypt the parameters, send the encrypted string as a parameter in the URL, like: `?params=the-encrypted-string` and then decrypt that string on the target page to access the parameters. However, before doing that, make sure you actually _need_ to do that. Sending "secret" data in the URL is seldom necessary. There's probably a better way of solving it.

Comment: indeed I think it's not necessary, in fact as I get values in the url for to display it, I just want to make the url more difficult to modify and not have "indexTest.php? client = Balmain & jira = Evo8&contact=Balmain@yahoo.fr " i can use URLrewrintting ?

Comment: If it is user input anyway, then why encrypting it? If you really do not want users to be able to manipulate the data, I suggest using POST instead of GET:

Comment: @Kapparina POST data can be manipulated too.

Comment: @d3L of course, I supposed our ways of thinking differed at that moment

Answer (score -1):

You can change "&", "=", and other characters to {random_string} and use a function for change {random_string} to normal characters again... or encrpyt/decrypt with a custom function...

Comment: Downvoted because if OP really wants to go down the "encryption/decryption" route he should be using something built for the job.

Comment: @d3L and that's why I say "with a custom function"... He can use something built or make something exclusive for what he need.